# Prove that Standard Deviation is always $\geq$ Mean Absolute Deviation

Tags: statistics, inequality, solution-verification, proof-explanation, standard-deviation

Where $$s = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$ and 
$$ M = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i - \bar{x}|$$

I came up with a sketchy proof for the case of $2$ values, but **I would like a way to generalize** (my "proof" unfortunately doesn't, as far as I can tell).

- Proof for $2$ values (I would appreciate feedback on this as well):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{(x_1 - \bar{x})^2 + (x_2 - \bar{x})^2} \geq \frac{1}{2} (|x_1- \bar{x}| + |x_2- \bar{x}|)$$

Now let $|x_1- \bar{x}| = a$ and $|x_2- \bar{x}| = b$ be the $2$ legs of a right triangle and $\sqrt{(x_1 - \bar{x})^2 + (x_2 - \bar{x})^2} = c$ its hypothenuse.

And let $\theta$ be the angle between $c$ and either $a$ or $b$.

Then $(\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta}) = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} (|x_1- \bar{x}| + |x_2- \bar{x}|)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{(x_1 - \bar{x})^2 + (x_2 - \bar{x})^2}}$

so that $$ \sqrt{2} \geq (\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta})$$

And we know that $\max(\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta}) = \sqrt{2}$. QED?

**I have no idea how to prove the general case, though**.

Comment: This looks like Cauchy-Schwarz to me.

Comment: @Emisor, how would you extend by induction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y_i = x_i - \bar{x}$ then by Cauchy-Schwarz we have the following:

$\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i| \frac{1}{n} \leq \|y\|_2 \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - \bar{x}|^2}$

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what $||y||2$ is. Is it supposed to be $y_i$ and is it the magnitude of $y_i$? Why not just have the absolute value sign, why the double abs value lines? And is the $2$ "magnitude of $y$ times $2$?

Comment: the $||y||$ is a notation from linear algebra of the norm of a vector.  There there is some flexability in the definition of norm, with  $||y||_2$ as the "Euclidean norm" or $\sqrt {\sum y_i^2}.$

Comment: @DougM and jeremy radcliff : The proper notation is $\|y\|$, not $||y||$.  If the difference is not conspicuous enough to you, consider the difference between $||x|| ||y||$ and $\|x\|\|y\|$ coded respectively as ||x|| ||y|| and \|x\|\|y\|. $\qquad$

Comment: Is there a missing exponent of 2 in the last expression?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @user84413 You could square both sides and then you would have an exponent of 2 on the left side and no square roots on the right side but they are both equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I understand what you're saying, but don't you want $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\overline{x}|^\color{red}{2}$ on the right side?

Comment: @user84413 I see it now, you are right.  I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

An even more general result follows from Jensen's inequality since the square root function is concave:

$$E\left[|Z|\right]=E\left[\sqrt{Z^2}\right]\leq \sqrt{E\left[Z^2\right]},$$

so taking $Z=X-E[X]$ for $X$ uniformly distributed with $\text{supp}\{X\}=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ gives your desired inequality.